# Why does Debian records in 1080p and Ubuntu record in 720p

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnu-screen, recording

Last year I was using Debian Jessie 8 as my main linux os and I used to record my screen with `Record My Desktop` the resolution of the video rendered as 1080p but recently I have switched to Ubuntu 16.4 as my main os and I'm using `EasyScreenCast` to capture my screen but when the video renders the resolution is 720p, I can't edit the resolution on `EasyScreenCast` to be any higher because my laptops resolution is `1366x786`. I was wondering why Jessie can record at 1080p and Ubuntu can't, even tough the screen display size is the same.

Comment: Are you able to record in 1080p when using Record My Desktop on Ubuntu?

Comment: Different versions of EasyScreenCast, where in the later one they added a check? Have you read the documentation to find out how you can configure it directly, and possibly overwrite the check?

Comment: @Peschke no on Ubuntu I can only record in 720p